# Getting red spot after 3 days of Tb Skin test

Tags: test-results, tuberculosis

My friend got tb skin test last three day. There is no swell spot or redness and the result of the test is negative. But on **day 4**, he start to have redness spot on the injection area and a bit itchy.

#### Does it mean he has tb virus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [tuberculosis is caused by a bacterium, not by a virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuberculosis).

There are a number of different skin tests used for tuberculosis.  The common ones are the [Mantoux test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantoux_test), the [tine test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tine_test), and the no-longer-used [Heaf test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaf_test).  All three of them indicate potential tuberculosis infection by measuring the presence and/or size of the firm raised area at the injection site after a certain amount of time; the [NHS's instructions for administering the Mantoux test](https://web.archive.org/web/20100215105953/http://www.immunisation.nhs.uk/files/mantouxtest.pdf) specifically call out itching of the injection site as normal, and state that any redness should be ignored when judging the results.